# Delete Child Posts

Tags: posts, child-pages, children

I'm trying to delete all child posts when the parent is deleted.

The parent post deletes just fine, but the child posts are not properly deleting.

Here's the code I have in place now:

```
$args = array( 
        'post_parent' => $parentid,
        'post_type' => 'custom-type'
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    if ($posts) {

        // Delete all the Children of the Parent Page
        foreach($posts as $post){

            wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);

        }

    }

    // Delete the Parent Page
    wp_delete_post($parentid, true);
```

What it should do is loop through and get the posts that are the child of `$parentid` and delete them, then delete the parent post.

Currently, it just deletes the parent post, but leaves all the children behind.

I'm looking at my database and the child pages are definitely created correctly with the correct `post_parent` id.

Is there a way to get all child posts and delete them?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $parentid,
    'post_type' => 'custom-type'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if (is_array($posts) && count($posts) > 0) {

    // Delete all the Children of the Parent Page
    foreach($posts as $post){

        wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);

    }

}

// Delete the Parent Page
wp_delete_post($parentid, true);
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much!!! 

Mind sharing why this worked and not the way I had it before, just so I can actually have an understanding?

Comment: Actually, I lied. It worked once, but now it's not working again.

Comment: Of course! The `get_posts` function returns either an array (if there are results) or null. You could also write `if($posts != null){` but I prefer writing conditional statements that check what you DO expect than on what you DON'T expect (in case WP changes in the future and starts returning something different on no result). Glad I could help!

Comment: What do you mean with 'worked once'? Once every session?

Comment: I created a parent post and 3 child posts, then ran the delete function and it worked. Then I created a parent again with 3 more child posts and it only deleted the parent page again.

Comment: I think this is actually working correctly now. . . I think I might have another issue that's not passing the correct parent id to the function.

Comment: If you're unable to fix it you can always open a new question :)

Comment: It's fixed. Your code helped fix the delete child posts issue, I just had a second issue with passing the parent ID to the delete function. Now all is in working order. Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hook into `delete_post`. The code below should run recursively and will delete if there are grandchilds too. *code not tested*

```
add_action('delete_post', 'wpse53967_clear_all_childs');

function wpse53967_clear_all_childs($post_id){
    $childs = get_post(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'post-type' 
    );

    if(empty($childs))
        return;

    foreach($childs as $post){
        wp_delete_post($post->ID, true); // true => bypass trash and permanently delete
    }
}
```