# Function to delete a post, it's children and it's grand children (half way there already)

Tags: query, php, customization

I've got a function working to delete a post and it's children. How can I amend this to delete it's grand children too?

```
<?php
function delete_post($sectionid)
{
    global $post;
    $deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true', get_delete_post_link( $sectionid) );

    if (current_user_can('edit_post', $sectionid)) {
    echo '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="' . $deletepostlink . '">Delete  this </a> </span>';
    }
}

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');

function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id )
{
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order'=> 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_type' => 'bucket'
        );

        // Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
        $children = get_children( $args );
        global $wpdb;

        foreach($children as $child){
            $childs[$child->ID] = $child->ID;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE ID IN   (" . implode( ', ', $childs ) . ")";
        $wpdb->query($sql);
        $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_redirect( $referer );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I need another `foreach`, but my PHP is only basic so far.

Comment: Try this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53989/2807

Comment: @DaveRomsey thanks for that Dave, I did see that but wasnt quite sure how to amend my markup to suit! Will keep on trying though and going to continue my online tuition of php / wordpress! Getting there though

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1. get all the ids of direct children
2. get all ids of grand children
3. combine
4. trash

   ```
   function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id )
   {
   if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {

       $args = array(
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'post_parent' => $post_id,
           'post_type' => 'bucket',
           'fields' => 'ids', // get only the ids, it's all we need
       );

       // get all children ids
       $children = get_posts( $args );
       $all_parents = array_merge( [ $post_id ], $children );

       // get all grand_children
       $args['post_parent__in'] = $children;
       unset( $args['post_parent'] ); // we're using the above array now

       $grand_children = get_posts( $args );

       // $all_posts now contains all affected ids
       $all_posts = array_merge( $all_parents, $grand_children );

       foreach($all_posts as $child){
           wp_trash_post( $child ); // use this unless you have good reason to query directly
       }

       $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
       wp_redirect( $referer );
       exit;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey, apologies for late response! This isn't working for me, it's only deleting top two levels!